# How to manage a JInternalFrame calling another JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a JDesktopPane with this code.

```
public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
/**
 * Creates new form Portada
 */
public static JDesktopPane desktop;

public JDesktopPane getDesktop() {
    return desktop;
}

public Menu() {
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    setContentPane(desktop);

    desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    initComponents();
}
}
```

then i add the new components like this

```
desktop.add(orden);
```

and when i want to call them i use

```
if(e.getSource()==jMenuItem1_1){
        orden.setVisible(true);
        desktop.setSelectedFrame(orden);
        desktop.moveToFront(orden);
        try {
            orden.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem i get is that when "orden" wants to pop out another JInternalFrame i use the next code.

```
searchSupplier.setVisible(true);
    Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop().add(searchSupplier);
    Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop()
            .moveToFront(searchSupplier);
    try {
        searchSupplier.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I execute the event more than 2 times i get the next error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
```

Where should i add the new JInternalFrame to the DesktopPane? or to Orden?, or What can i do to fix this error?

Comment: please @mKorbel i really need help with this...

Comment: How is seatchSupplier created? Do you create a new instance each time you call the method or are you using the same instance

Comment: I'm using the same instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the searchSupplier frame is already on the desktop, it is unlikely that you will able to add it again. Try using `getParent` to determine if the frame needs to be added

```
if (searchSupplier.getParent() == null) {
    Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop().add(searchSupplier);
}
searchSupplier.setVisible(true);
Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop().moveToFront(searchSupplier);
try {
    searchSupplier.setSelected(true);
} catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There is no way to express my gratitude to you man... If you ever come to Peru I pay you a big meal. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Washu Hmm, you make me jealous.

Comment: Next time i ask a question you can help me :P I will gladly offer another meal ;)

Comment: @Washu If and when you can, help others solve there problems, that is more repayment that I would ever deserve ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I usually hang out in chatroom because at my current level i can't provide full answers, i help other newbies to find relevant information in the internet that may help them with their questions. I'm always in Java chat :)