# How to to call JInternalFrame from another JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, call, jinternalframe

it is posible ?? call JInternalFrame from another JInternalFrame ??
if so how?

i've looking for the answer over many hours..
found some question before..

in here [How to manage a JInternalFrame calling another JInternalFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420401/how-to-manage-a-jinternalframe-calling-another-jinternalframe)

I dont know that means getInstance? I think thts a container for a contentPane..
same as this question

[is there any way call other JinternalFrame from an JinternalFrame but, in the desktopPane of of main Jframe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598909/is-there-any-way-call-other-jinternalframe-from-an-jinternalframe-but-in-the-de)

both of that didnt give a right answer. the error always like this..

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

help me, I've spend my day for this sad question...

or for a another way it is posible blind/return a value to the main JFrame???

thanks u :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends.  If you only want to interact with the other `JInternalFrame` itself (and not a specific instance of the frame), you could use [`JDesktopPane#getAllFrames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#getAllFrames%28%29)

If you need to execute a specific/custom method, you would actually be better passing a reference of the frame to the frame that wants to call it...

Or even better, develop some kind of model that can be modified and fire events, separating the logic from user interface